# How to configure Windows 7 firewall outbound rules for symlinked applications?

Tags: windows-7, mount, firewall, symbolic-link, windows-firewall

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate.

I have set the built in firewall in outbound white list mode (block unless allowed by a rule).

Now I'm trying to configure some outbound rules for the built in firewall.
If I have

`C:\Dir\app.exe`

that tries to make outbound connections it gets blocked by default and if I add a rule specifically allowing it, it goes through. So far, perfectly fine. Everything works according to the fine manual. :)

The problem is the filesystem structure that I use is a bit more complex (flexible):
I have various disk drives aside from the one windows is installed on. Each volume (partition)(that Windows can read) is mounted under

`C:\mnt`

like this:

`C:\mnt\1`

`C:\mnt\2`

`C:\mnt\3`

Then I use junctions (symlinks) from (for example):

`C:\Apps` to `C:\mnt\1\^W7_Apps`

`C:\mnt\1\^W7_Apps` has inside `Network\Iron\Iron.exe` so that makes

`C:\Apps\Network\Iron\Iron.exe` a valid path (that is used to start that particular browser).

This path is, for all intents and purposes (heh) as real a path as any. Windows Explorer sees it and is able to use it. Other file managers too.

Back to the firewall.

If I add a rule that allows `C:\Apps\Network\Iron\Iron.exe` to make outbound connections, it does not work. At all.

If instead I add a rule that allows `C:\mnt\1\^W7_Apps\Network\Iron\Iron.exe` (shouldn't make a difference but hey) to make outbound connections, it also does not work. At all.

I've installed [Windows Firewall Notifier](http://wfn.codeplex.com). This plugs into the Windows Firewall framework and adds some missing functionality. One missing function that it adds is notifications on outbound connection attempts from applications not already covered by a rule. When I then tested `C:\Apps\Network\Iron\Iron.exe` again, a popup asked me if I wanted to allow 
`\device\harddiskvolume8\^w7_apps\network\iron\iron.exe` to make that connection.

BINGO! I thought. Internally, the firewall sees the path to the binary in that [Object Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Manager_(Windows)) namespace notation. Thank you fine manual for never mentioning this.

But sadly, allowing that connection creates a rule that also doesn't work.

Help. :)

Not sure if this question is best posted here on SuperUser or should it go to ServerFault or StackOverflow or to bugs@microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure about Windows 7, in Windows 10 using the 'real' path - in our case using `%ProgramFiles%\CompanyName\ProgramType\%Version%\program.exe` - worked with the Windows Firewall. Note that in our case the system environment variable `Version` contains a version specific part of the path, e.g. `V12.0.1.23`.